# PHP Implode not working with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two arrays, $gDatabaseKeyNames (list of column names) and $gDatabaseKeyValues (a list of variable names containing values from a script). The variable names are generated dynamically so I keep track of them for an insert.

Rather than listing all of the columns and value variables, I tried this

```
$cols = implode(", ", array_values($gDatabaseKeyNames));
$vals = implode(", ", array_values($gDatabaseKeyValues));

$query = "INSERT INTO pings (survey_id, $cols) VALUES ('$surveyID', $vals)";                              
mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

But none of my actual values show up in the database (they are inserted as 0s - all my columns are numeric).

If I echo $query, I see this, which is the correct formatting:

```
INSERT INTO pings (survey_id, latitude, longitude, pingTimestamp) VALUES ('15', '$Dlatitude', '$Dlongitude', FROM_UNIXTIME('$DtimeStamp'))
```

However, if I change $query to

```
$query = INSERT INTO pings (survey_id, latitude, longitude, pingTimestamp) VALUES ('$surveyID', '$Dlatitude', '$Dlongitude', FROM_UNIXTIME('$DtimeStamp'));
```

It works perfectly!

Why isn't PHP interpreting the variables in the implode? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that $cols has the literal value `'$Dlatitude', '$Dlongitude', etc...`. PHP does not "double-interpolate" strings. It'll replace $cols with its values, but will NOT replace $Dlatitude with that variable's value. In other words, you're literally inserting some strings-that-look-like-PHP-variable-names into your numeric fields.

What is in the $gDatabaseKeyValues/Names arrays?

Comment: $gDatabaseKeyValues = ("latitude", "longitude", ..)  $gDatabaseKeyNames = ("'$Dlatitude'", "'$Dlongitude'", ..)

Comment: Remove the quotes from around the $Dxxx vars, so their VALUES go into the array, not their names.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused because of string/number problems. You should consider changing the database engine (Consider [PDO](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) and use prepared statements to bind the parameters to your query the right way.